# OfficeJS Outlook Add-in Does Not Install

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, office-store

**UPDATE #1:**

TL;DR: I want to target:

- Outlook 2016 or later
- Outlook on the Web
- Outlook 2016 for Mac
- Outlook for iOS
- Outlook for Android

I require Mailbox 1.5 in order to support [calling the Outlook REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api) and to  support [pinnable taskpanes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane).

Since pinnable taskpanes are only supported in Outlook 2016 for Windows, and because [Mailbox 1.5 is currently only supported in Outlook on the Web](https://dev.office.com/add-in-availability), I will need to set Mailbox 1.5 in the `<VersionOverrides>` sections of the manifest.

Based on the validation report:

```
Your add-in manifest includes Tablet Settings and Phone Settings, however 
Mailbox 1.4 is used in the core of your manifest. This mailbox is not
supported in the Outlook Web App.
```

That sounds like it conflicts with what [Office Add-in host and platform availability](https://dev.office.com/add-in-availability) says. So, I have set Mailbox 1.3 in the base level of the manifest.

---

Here is my manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>3042ed3a-6ca5-4b37-b5e3-a591f5605332</Id>
  <Version>1.0.1.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Leap Legal Software</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="LEAP Mail Manager" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Save your mail to LEAP."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-64.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-128.png" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://leap.force.com/us/s/" />
  <AppDomains>
    <!--LEAP Add-in Domains -->
    <AppDomain>https://outlookapp-dev.leap365.com/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://outlookapp-test.leap365.com/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://outlookapp.leap365.com/</AppDomain>
    <!--TitleX Add-in Domains -->
    <AppDomain>https://outlookapp.dev.titlex.com.au/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://outlookapp.test.titlex.com.au/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://outlookapp.titlex.com.au/</AppDomain>
    <!-- LEAP Auth -->
    <AppDomain>https://auth-dev.leap.services/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://auth-test.leap.services/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://auth.leap.services/</AppDomain>
    <!-- TitleX Auth -->
    <AppDomain>https://login.dev.titlex.com.au/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://login.test.titlex.com.au/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://login.titlex.com.au/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://login.dev.titlex.co.uk/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://login.test.titlex.co.uk/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://login.titlex.co.uk/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://login.dev.titlex.com/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://login.test.titlex.com/</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://login.titlex.com/</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.3" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/index.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>280</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
      <TabletSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/index.html" />
        <RequestedHeight>280</RequestedHeight>
      </TabletSettings>
      <PhoneSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/index.html" />
      </PhoneSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" /></Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.5" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Leap.Functions.Url" />
          <!-- Message Read -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <CustomTab id="TabLeap">
              <Group id="Leap.Group1">
                <Label resid="Leap.Group1Label" />
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Leap.DefaultCommand">
                  <Label resid="Leap.DefaultCommand.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Leap.DefaultCommand.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Leap.DefaultCommand.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Leap.Icon.16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Leap.Icon.32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Leap.Icon.80" />
                    <bt:Image size="20" resid="Leap.Icon.20" />
                    <bt:Image size="24" resid="Leap.Icon.24" />
                    <bt:Image size="40" resid="Leap.Icon.40" />
                    <bt:Image size="48" resid="Leap.Icon.48" />
                    <bt:Image size="64" resid="Leap.Icon.64" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Leap.Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
              <Label resid="Leap.TabLabel"/>
            </CustomTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.16" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.32" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.80" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-80.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.20" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-20.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.24" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-24.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.25" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-25.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.40" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-40.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.48" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-48.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.64" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-64.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Leap.Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/index.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Leap.Functions.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/functions.html" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="Leap.TabLabel" DefaultValue="LEAP Mail Manager" />
        <bt:String id="Leap.Group1Label" DefaultValue="LEAP" />
        <bt:String id="Leap.DefaultCommand.Label" DefaultValue="LEAP Mail Manager" />
        <bt:String id="Leap.DefaultCommand.Title" DefaultValue="LEAP Mail Manager" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="Leap.DefaultCommand.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to show the add-in." />
        <bt:String id="Leap.Description" DefaultValue="Save your mail to LEAP." />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
    <!-- NOTE: TO SUPPORT A PINNABLE TASKPANE AND MOBILEFORMFACTOR -->
    <VersionOverrides 
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.5">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.5" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="Leap.Functions.Url" />
            <!-- Message Read -->
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <CustomTab id="TabLeap">
                <Group id="Leap.Group1">
                  <Label resid="Leap.Group1Label" />
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Leap.DefaultCommand">
                    <Label resid="Leap.DefaultCommand.Label" />
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="Leap.DefaultCommand.Label" />
                      <Description resid="Leap.DefaultCommand.Tooltip" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Leap.Icon.16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Leap.Icon.32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Leap.Icon.80" />
                      <bt:Image size="20" resid="Leap.Icon.20" />
                      <bt:Image size="24" resid="Leap.Icon.24" />
                      <bt:Image size="40" resid="Leap.Icon.40" />
                      <bt:Image size="48" resid="Leap.Icon.48" />
                      <bt:Image size="64" resid="Leap.Icon.64" />
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Leap.Taskpane.Url" />
                      <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                  <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
                </Group>
                <Label resid="Leap.TabLabel"/>
              </CustomTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
            <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
          </DesktopFormFactor>
          <!-- See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-mobile-support -->
          <MobileFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="Leap.Functions.Url" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MobileMessageReadCommandSurface">
              <Group id="Leap.Group1">
                <Label resid="Leap.Group1Label" />
                <Control xsi:type="MobileButton" id="Leap.DefaultCommand">
                  <Label resid="Leap.DefaultCommand.Label" />
                  <Icon xsi:type="bt:MobileIconList">
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="1" resid="Leap.Icon.25" />
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="2" resid="Leap.Icon.25" />
                    <bt:Image size="25" scale="3" resid="Leap.Icon.25" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="1" resid="Leap.Icon.32" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="2" resid="Leap.Icon.32" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" scale="3" resid="Leap.Icon.32" />
                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="1" resid="Leap.Icon.48" />
                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="2" resid="Leap.Icon.48" />
                    <bt:Image size="48" scale="3" resid="Leap.Icon.48" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Leap.Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </MobileFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.16" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.32" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.80" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-80.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.20" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-20.png" />
          <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.24" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-24.png" />
          <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.25" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-25.png" />
          <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.40" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-40.png" />
          <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.48" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-48.png" />
          <bt:Image id="Leap.Icon.64" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/images/icon-64.png" />
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="Leap.Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/index.html" />
          <bt:Url id="Leap.Functions.Url" DefaultValue="https://outlookapp.leap365.com/functions.html" />
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="Leap.TabLabel" DefaultValue="LEAP Mail Manager" />
          <bt:String id="Leap.Group1Label" DefaultValue="LEAP" />
          <bt:String id="Leap.DefaultCommand.Label" DefaultValue="LEAP Mail Manager" />
          <bt:String id="Leap.DefaultCommand.Title" DefaultValue="LEAP Mail Manager" />
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="Leap.DefaultCommand.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to show the add-in." />
          <bt:String id="Leap.Description" DefaultValue="Save your mail to LEAP." />
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Here is the [validate-office-addin](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-addin-validator) result for the above add-in manifest:

```
Calling validation service. This might take a moment...
-------------------------------------
Validation: Passed
Based on the requirements specified in your manifest, your add-in can run on the following platforms; your add-in will be tested on these platforms when you submit it to the Office Store:
  - Outlook 2013 Service Pack 1 or later
  - Outlook 2016 or later
  - Outlook on the Web
  - Outlook 2016 for Mac
  - Outlook for iOS
  - Outlook for Android
Important: This analysis is based on the requirements specified in your manifest and does not account for any runtime JavaScript calls within your add-in. For information about which API sets and features are supported on each platform, see Office Add-in host and platfo
rm availability. (https://dev.office.com/add-in-availability).

*This does not include mobile apps. You can opt-in to support mobile apps when you submit your add-in.
-------------------------------------
```

However, the validation report from Microsoft says:

```
Your add-in is not working in Outlook 2016, Outlook 2013, Outlook for Mac, 
the Outlook app on iOS or in the Outlook app on Android. Your add-in is not 
available to be inserted in the above platforms. If you do not support 2013 
SP1 because you are using an API only available in 2016/Online, you must put 
these apis in the requirements tag in your manifest. If you are not using an 
API only available in 2016/Online, then you must support 2013 SP1.
```

I have [side-loaded the add-in from OWA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing).

I can see the add-in on:

- Outlook 2016 or later (Windows)
- Outlook on the Web (OWA)

I have yet to test if the add-in appears on Outlook 2016 for Mac.

For the life of me I can't seem to get the add-in to show up on:

- Outlook 2013 Service Pack 1 or later
- Outlook for iOS
- Outlook for Android

I don't understand why. Am I missing something in the manifest? Have I perhaps misconfigured the manifest? Please help.

Comment: You should be able to use 1.4 in your core manifest as the requirement set. Office-Addin-Validator might be out of date and you can submit an issue on github for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding some detail to the Add-in and Store team's responses.

The Outlook 2013 problem stems from two conflicting rules that Outlook is following:

- You've declared your minimum mailbox version of `1.3` in the core manifest.
- You've also declared a `VersionOverridesV1_0` section with a minimum version of `1.5`

The validation tool is declaring support for Outlook 2013 Service Pack 1 or later because (as the Store team mentioned), this version of Outlook supports `1.3`.

Outlook 2013 Service Pack 1 or later also supports [Add-in Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook)  via `VersionOverridesV1_0`. As soon as Outlook sees you have a Add-in Commands declared, it will pivot to using add-in commands. However, since these are defined as requiring `1.5` Outlook 2013 is unable to render them.

In order for your Add-in Commands to show up in Outlook 2013, you need to make sure the minimum version you're requiring within `VersionOverridesV1_0` is `1.4` or lower (note that `VersionOverridesV1_1` should remain at `1.5`).

Comment: Marked this as the answer because it indirectly helped me to solve my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Support for Outlook mobile is added by defining the `MobileFormFactor` element in `VersionOverridesV1_1`. See [here for more information on MobileFormFactor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-mobile-support)

Mailbox 1.5 is not supported in Outlook 2013 ( see [here](https://dev.office.com/add-in-availability) for availability information) For your add-in to appear in Outlook  2013, you need to use Mailbox 1.4 or lower

Comment: Please see my manifest: I am specifying `<MobileFormFactor>` in `VersionOverrides v1.1`. If `Mailbox 1.5` is not supported in Outlook 2013, why does the validator list it as a supported platform? I will edit my question to provide more context.

Comment: I've added the Outlook-addin tag to get the Outlook add-ins team to jump in to help out here. I believe this is because the requirements in the core of your manifest have mailbox 1.3; but the Outlook team are best placed to assist further.